# How do I make app.handlers suport undo (CTRL+Z)

Tags: python, animation, add-on

I'm using an operator to animate objects via `handlers.frame_change_pre` but any <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, shutdown all my animated objects.
How can I fix my "Undo" to remove just the last added handler (in the history) everytime I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

---

*Below an add-on to reproduce the mistake:*

Select an object. Call `SimpleOperator` in the search to animate some objects and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "handlers suport undo",
    "version": (0, 5),
    "blender": (2, 74, 0),
    "category": "handlers test",
    }

import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent


def main(context):
    # get objects and Vars
    obj  = bpy.data.scenes[0].objects.active
    bg  = "HdlName_"

    @persistent
    def track(scene):

        #do something
        obj.location += obj.location * 0.009 
        print(bg+obj.name)

    #new handler 
    track.__name__ = bg + str( obj.as_pointer() )
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(track)



class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}



def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: It looks like handlers are immune to UNDO even if they're added with a register / undo operator, as shown.  One way to achieve what you are after is to add a custom property to the context.object with the operator, and have one handler that works on an obj list [ob for ob in scene.objects if "prop" in ob.keys()]  Hitting ctrl-z removes the custom property, and hence removes last added object from the handler.  I recall coming across similar issues trying to do something like this.